# How to hide the second uibaritem in swift 2

Tags: swift2

I have 2 bar items as shown below how can I hide the second one  when I click on the first one ? ( i tried earthBtn.hidden = true but its not working. Here is my code:

```
    let earthImg = UIImage(named: "earth0")
    let earthBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: earthImg, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "earthBtn_click")

    let messageImg = UIImage(named: "categories1")
    let messageBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: messageImg, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "messageBtn_click")

    let buttonArray = NSArray(objects: earthBtn,messageBtn)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttonArray as? [UIBarButtonItem]


    func messageBtn_click() {


    earthBtn.hidden = true // is not working 


 }
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, you cannot hide a `UIBarButtonItem` and what you can do is make the color transparent and disable it, and when you wanna use it back then you have to enable it and then give it a color:

Define it globally as class variable :

```
let earthBtn = UIBarButtonItem()
```

Use it like :

```
earthBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: earthImg, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "earthBtn_click")
```

hide the button:

```
func messageBtn_click() {


    earthBtn.enabled = false
    earthBtn.color = UIColor.clearColor()


 }
```

Comment: @ Nata Mio thanks for your reply i get this message use of unresolved identifier 'earthBtn'

Comment: @user3700449 , what is the button you want to hide ? give me the name ?

Comment: @ Nata the button i want to hide is the earthBtn

Comment: Since I cannot hide a UIBarButtonItem as you said I am going to use self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.enabled = true.

Comment: I'm sorry but the code you suggested didn't work. I enabled it using different code which is self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.enabled = true. thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Then its your question wasn't clear, you haven't asked about navigation item and its on the right or left! your fault ...i've answered depends on what i see here !!!  welcome @user3700449